# tikz-3dplot causes problems to let operator

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates, tikz-3dplot

I am trying to use the 3d-plot library. The plan is to define some basic 2d coordinates at the beginning and then use them to define all kind of 3d points, using the "let" operator:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\begin{document}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{0}{0} %doing nothing for now
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
\draw[red,->] (0,0,0)--(1,0,0);
\draw[red,->] (0,0,0)--(0,1,0); %just for reference

\coordinate (A) at (1,1);
\draw let \p1=(A) in (0,0,0)--(\x1,1,0); %this is problematic
\draw[green] (1,1,0)--(28.45,1,0);
\draw[blue] let \p1=(A) in (0,0,0)--(\x1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The problem is that the output does not make any sense:
-tikz seems to know how to draw point (1,1,0) (first point of green line).
-tikz seems to know that \x1 of (A) equals 1 (blue line).
-tikz somehow multiplies \x1 by ~28.45 for no apparent reason, when \x1 is used inside 3d coordinates.
(note that experimenting with defining (A) to be 3d - i.e. (1,1,0) - changed nothing)

I find this problem fascinating, so I'd like it very much to wrap my head around it, but if someone has apart from it a solution on how to define a pair of numbers to use afterwards in tikz, behaving well with tikz-3dplot, I would also be interested

[image: output]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE! The `let` operator works still fine. The problem you are seeing is that the 3d coordinate system installed by `tikz-3dplot` tacitly works with `cm` units whereas the `calc` syntax yields `pt`. To see this more explicitly, let's look at the definition of `\tdplotsetmaincoords` in `tikz-3dplot.sty`,

```
\newcommand{\tdplotsetmaincoords}[2]{%
%perform some trig for the display transformation
%
%
%store the user-specified angles for possible future use
\pgfmathsetmacro{\tdplotmaintheta}{#1}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\tdplotmainphi}{#2}
%
%
\tdplotcalctransformmainscreen
%
%now here is where the output is performed
\tikzset{tdplot_main_coords/.style={x={(\raarot cm,\rbarot cm)},y={(\rabrot cm, \rbbrot cm)},z={(\racrot cm, \rbcrot cm)}}}%
}
```

Here, the coordinates get (unfortunately, one may perhaps add) multiplied by `cm`. (The macros `\racrot` are just entries of the rotation matrix, i.e. an orthogonal 3x3 matrix parametrized in the conventions of the package.) I should, however, add that overall I **love** that package, so I am very far from criticizing the author. The more so since the problem can be fixed really easily.

The arguably simplest fix is to convert back to `cm` by just dividing by `1cm/1pt`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\begin{document}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{0}{0} %doing nothing for now
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
\draw[red,->] (0,0,0)--(1,0,0);
\draw[red,->] (0,0,0)--(0,1,0); %just for reference

\coordinate (A) at (1,1);
\draw let \p1=(A) in (0,0,0)--({\x1*1pt/1cm},1,0); %this is problematic
%\draw[green] (1,1,0)--(28.45,1,0);
\draw[blue] let \p1=(A) in (0,0,0)-- (\x1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: P.S. You might be interested in [this commit](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/git/ci/31165f2f43d419e1a921a1881bf25743592577a7/).

Comment: Perfect answer. Thank you very much. I knew I had seen this 28.sth before :)  P.S. This \coord thing seems indeed interesting, I will check it out.

Comment: @D.Bogiokas You're welcome! There are ideas to add the orthonormal transformations to the `3d` library.  However, if this happens, it won't happen tomorrow, and questions like this one will certainly greatly help to avoid some pitfalls.