# TikZ: Advantage of position values attached with a unit?

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, draw, units, unit-of-measure

Regarding `TikZ`-images: When should I type positioning values attached with a unit (e.g. `\draw (0cm, 0cm)...`) and when should I type them without a unit (e.g. simply `\draw (0, 0)...`)?

---

**Minimum Working Example No. 1:**

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
           \draw (0, 0) rectangle (4, 4);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

**Minimum Working Example No. 2:**

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
       \draw (0cm, 0cm) rectangle (4cm, 4cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

**Screenshot of the result from MWE no. 1:**

[image: Screenshot of MWE no. 1]

---

**Screenshot of the result from MWE no. 2:**

[image: Screenshot of MWE no. 2]

---

As you can see, both codes will create the completely same picture. Therefore: What is the advantage of `\draw (0cm, 0cm)...` over `\draw (0, 0)...` and vice versa?

Comment: default unit in `tikz` (with some exception, for example at `xshift`, `yshift`) is cm, so, if you stick with it you not need to write it explicit.

Comment: Ti*k*Z interprets `(x,y)` as `x*e_1+y*e_2`, where the defaults for the unit vectors `e_i` are `e_1=(1cm,0)` and `e_2=(0,1cm)`. The perhaps clearest explanation can be found [in this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31606/121799) by LoopSpace, which was written at a time when Jake still had questions. And I disagree with @Zarko, the default unit for Ti*k*Z is pt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These two expressions are in principle very different and give "accidentally" the same result. IMHO the clearest discussion of this site can be found [in this nice answer by LoopSpace](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31606/121799), out of which I recycle some relevant parts here. Ti*k*Z interprets `(x,y)` rather differently depending on whether or not `x` and `y` carry units.

1. If they are dimensionless, then the coordinate `(x,y)` means `x times unit vector in x direction plus y times unit vector in y direction`.
2. If they carry units, then it just means `x to the right and y up`.

By default, the unit vector in `x` direction is `(1cm,0)` and the unit vector in `y` direction is `(0,1cm)`, such that for two dimensionless numbers `x` and `y` *in the default settings* `(x,y)` and `(xcm,ycm)` yield the same result, which is what your MWEs illustrate. However, if we change the basis vectors, this is no longer true, as the following example shows (using a rectangle may not be the best example to illustrate these issues, but at least it is simple).

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily] 
        \begin{scope}[local bounding box=standard]
           \begin{scope}[local bounding box=without units 1]
            \draw (0, 0) rectangle (4, 4);
           \end{scope}
           \node[above] at (without units 1.north){without units};
           \begin{scope}[xshift=5cm,local bounding box=with units 1]
            \draw (0cm, 0cm) rectangle (4cm, 4cm);
           \end{scope}
           \node[above] at (with units 1.north){with units};
        \end{scope}   
        \node[rotate=90,above=2em] at (standard.west){standard unit vectors};
        \begin{scope}[local bounding box=nonstandard,
        yshift=-5cm,x={(0.75,0.25)},y={(0,0.8)}]   
           \begin{scope}[local bounding box=without units 2]
            \draw (0, 0) rectangle (4, 4);
           \end{scope}
           \node[above] at (without units 2.north){without units};
           \begin{scope}[xshift=5cm,local bounding box=with units 2]
            \draw (0cm, 0cm) rectangle (4cm, 4cm);
           \end{scope}
           \node[above] at (with units 2.north){with units};
        \end{scope}   
        \node[rotate=90,above=2em] at (nonstandard.west){nonstandard unit vectors};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Internally pgf uses pt as units, which is why the pgf key `xshift=2` yields a shift by `2pt` (as [remarked by Zarko](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/483577/tikz-advantage-of-position-values-attached-with-a-unit#comment1222580_483577)). However, this does not mean that the radii of circles get interpreted as pt, rather, as explained [in this nice answer by LoopSpace](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31606/121799) the command `\draw[ultra thick] (0,0) circle[x radius=2,y radius=2];` yields, in the default coordinate system, a circle of radius 2cm.

So a possible answer to the question

> When should I type positioning values attached with a unit (e.g. `\draw
>   (0cm, 0cm)...)` and when should I type them without a unit (e.g. simply
>   `\draw (0, 0)...)`?

is

> It depends on what you need and/or are doing. In many situations you
>   install nonstandard coordinate systems for a reason, which is why you
>   may not want to add `cm` when dealing with them.

Side-remark: the `tikz-3dplot` package adds cm to all coordinates, which [can lead to confusion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/474136/121799) in some cases.

Comment: *Complement:* And when we mix `(2,3cm)` we obtain `2*x+(0cm,3cm)` where `x` is the x-base vector. But if we mix inside the same component like `(1+1cm,3)` then 1 is used with the default `pt` unit, so is equivalent to `(1pt+1cm,0cm) + 3*y`.

Comment: @Kpym  I said nothing that would contradict that, There is a sheer endless list of such examples.

Answer (score 2):

In complement to [marmot's nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/483604/73317), the following picture may be helpful:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x={(2cm,2cm)}, y={(0cm,2cm)},
                    every node/.style={inner sep=2pt}]
  \draw[blue, ->] (0,0) -- (1,0) node[below right] {$\vec{x}$};
  \draw[blue, ->] (0,0) -- (0,1) node[above]       {$\vec{y}$};

  \begin{scope}[shift={(1,0)}]  % very different from shift={(1cm,0)}
  \draw[red, ->] (0cm,0cm) -- (1cm,0cm) node[right] {$\vec{u}$};
  \draw[red, ->] (0cm,0cm) -- (0cm,1cm) node[above] {$\vec{v}$};
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]