# Making a checkerboard with `foreach`

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

Why are these two diagrams different?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}


\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \y in {0,2,...,8}
{\foreach \x in {0,2,...,8}
{\draw[fill=black!50, xshift={(1/4)*sqrt(2)/2*\x*1cm}, yshift={(1/4)*sqrt(2)/2*\y*1cm}]
(0:{(1/4)*sqrt(2)/2}) -- (90:{(1/4)*sqrt(2)/2}) -- (180:{(1/4)*sqrt(2)/2}) -- (270:{(1/4)*sqrt(2)/2}) -- cycle;}
}

\draw ({-(1/4)*sqrt(2)/2},{-(1/4)*sqrt(2)/2}) rectangle ({(1/4)*9*sqrt(2)/2},{(1/4)*9*sqrt(2)/2});


\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.25cm, y=0.25cm]
\foreach \y in {0,2,...,8}
{\foreach \x in {0,2,...,8}
{\draw[fill=black!50, xshift={sqrt(2)/2*\x*1cm}, yshift={sqrt(2)/2*\y*1cm}] let \n1={sqrt(2)/2} in
(0:\n1) -- (90:\n1) -- (180:\n1) -- (270:\n1) -- cycle;}
}

\draw let \n1={sqrt(2)/2} in (-\n1,-\n1) rectangle ({9*\n1},{9*\n1});


\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second picture has a `[x=0.25cm, y=0.25cm]` which the first one does not.

- This is *not* equivalent to `scale=0.25`, which you may be looking for.
- You tell Ti*k*Z explicitly in the second picture `xshift={sqrt(2)/2*\X*1cm}, yshift={sqrt(2)/2*\Y*1cm}`, so it does not
  care about the lengths of the unit vectors but just follows your
  instructions.
- These lengths of the unit vectors do, however, have an
  impact on the sizes of the gray rectangles, and the rectangle at the
  end of the picture.
- Ti*k*Z treats dimensionless and dimensionful coordinates very differently, we usually do not care about this because we choose the standard unit vectors. If you choose different ones, you feel this. The perhaps clearest explanation of these issues
  is in [this nice
  answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31606/121799), which
  discusses circles, not rectangles, but the qualitative argument is
  the same.

BTW, it is not a good practice IMHO if you declare the loop
   variables `\x` and `\y` in some code that makes use of the calc
   syntax, which defines `\x` and `\y` on its own. Use e.g. `\X` and
   `\Y` instead.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}


\begin{document}

\paragraph{Original picture}~\par\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \Y in {0,2,...,8}
{\foreach \X in {0,2,...,8}
{\draw[fill=black!50, xshift={(1/4)*sqrt(2)/2*\X*1cm}, yshift={(1/4)*sqrt(2)/2*\Y*1cm}]
(0:{(1/4)*sqrt(2)/2}) -- (90:{(1/4)*sqrt(2)/2}) -- (180:{(1/4)*sqrt(2)/2}) -- (270:{(1/4)*sqrt(2)/2}) -- cycle;}
}

\draw ({-(1/4)*sqrt(2)/2},{-(1/4)*sqrt(2)/2}) rectangle ({(1/4)*9*sqrt(2)/2},{(1/4)*9*sqrt(2)/2});
\end{tikzpicture}

\bigskip
\hrule
\bigskip

\paragraph{Second picture} This changes the unit vectors/units but the \texttt{xshift}s and
\texttt{yshift}s are specified explicitly, i.e.\ with explicit lengths, and do
\emph{not} get multiplied by the unit vectors:\par\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.25cm, y=0.25cm]
\foreach \Y in {0,2,...,8}
{\foreach \X in {0,2,...,8}
{\draw[fill=black!50, xshift={sqrt(2)/2*\X*1cm}, yshift={sqrt(2)/2*\Y*1cm}] 
let \n1={sqrt(2)/2} in 
(0:\n1) -- (90:\n1) -- (180:\n1) -- (270:\n1) -- cycle;}
}

\draw let \n1={sqrt(2)/2} in (-\n1,-\n1) rectangle ({9*\n1},{9*\n1});
\end{tikzpicture}

\bigskip
\hrule
\bigskip


\paragraph{Alternative} This is what you may be looking for:\par\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.25]
\foreach \Y in {0,2,...,8}
{\foreach \X in {0,2,...,8}
{\draw[fill=black!50, xshift={sqrt(2)/2*\X*1cm}, yshift={sqrt(2)/2*\Y*1cm}] 
let \n1={sqrt(2)/2} in 
(0:\n1) -- (90:\n1) -- (180:\n1) -- (270:\n1) -- cycle;}
}

\draw let \n1={sqrt(2)/2} in (-\n1,-\n1) rectangle ({9*\n1},{9*\n1});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you saying that `xshift={sqrt(2)/2*\x*1cm}` and `yshift={sqrt(2)/2*\y*1cm}` ignore the options `x=0.25cm, y=0.25cm` in the `tikzpicture` environment?

Comment: What is the difference between the options `x=0.25cm, y=0.25cm` and `scale=0.25` in the `tikzpicture` environment?

Comment: @AgalnamedDesire Yes, `x=0.25cm, y=0.25cm` and `scale=0.25` are *very* different, at least in principle. So are the coordinates, say, `(0,1)` and `(0,1cm)`.  Apart from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31606/121799) maybe [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/483604/121799) may provide some additional insights.