# Trying to draw circle with Radius 30, is 30 pt and not matching with coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf

I currently have this:

```
\draw[line width = 2mm] (0,0) circle (30 pt);
```

This should be a circle with radius 30. But this is not the case. Indeed, when I want to go from a point on a circle to another point, I get rather ridiculous results.

```
\draw[line width = 2mm] (-30,0) -- (-60,-60);
```

So 30 pt does not mean the circle extends to a radius of 30 in the coordinate system as I need it to. Any help here would be appreciated.

Comment: it would be a lot easier  to understand your question if you provided a document that shows the problem rather than disconnected fragments.

Comment: The default unit vectors are 1cm long, not 1pt. Why not `circle(30)`?

Comment: @DevonClark You may be interested in [this discussion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/483577/tikz-advantage-of-position-values-attached-with-a-unit).